# How to stop program from starting a service Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, services

How do I stop a program from being able to start a service? The program in question is Badlion Client, and during its startup, the first thing it does it start (or install if not there) a service. I do not want the program to be able to start the service (BadlionAnticheat).

I have tried to do `sc Lock` before I open the program, but after I open and close the program, BadlionAnticheat shows as running. I cannot stop the program once it is started because it is kernel level and also marked as not stoppable.

I will consider any method of doing this.

Comment: `sc lock` will just lock the service manager database. You can try stopping the service after the program has started.

Comment: You might want to look into the Autoruns program that is part of the Sysinternals package. You can download the program from Microsoft, and it makes disabling a service easy.

Comment: @michaelg Thank you for suggesting that software, it is very helpful, but in this case, the service does not even show up, which might be an indication that it's Badlion's fault for so deeply hiding their driver to where it only shows up via command line.

Comment: "the service does not even show up".. that's probably because it isn't a service, its a driver.. similar.. but not the same.  The clue here is BadlionAnticheat.sys <- see the .sys?  This changes the methods you will need to use to circumvent this.. HEY... YOU WOULDN'T BE TRYING TO ***CHEAT*** at MineCraft WOULD YOU??

Comment: Also.. what makes you think the exe will still work if it can't load the service?  I bet it will not.  I would guess that Badlion has circumvented anything simple you can do.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Haha no I have no intention of cheating at videogames. The reason is that BadlionAnticheat blocks Cheat Engine, which I use for modding in other games. If I wanted to cheat, I'd just use impact or other hacked client. Also thanks for the heads up that it's a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the service via Nirsoft's **ServiWin**: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html.
If it doesn't let you, you can start **ServiWin** via **Advanced Run** (also from Nirsoft) but with "Run As..." =  "Trusted Installer": this way you can get rights almost anywhere in Windows...
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html

[Advanced Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUvJB.png)